# change of image and text properties when parent DIV Hover

Tags: jquery, css

Everyone

I am a beginner.
Let's raise the question by first courageing the stack overflow.

https://codepen.io/noxwon/pen/RwrmxKX

This is my code. As you can see it is basic. A lot of simple repetitive code

```
    $("#box-1").hover(
    function () {
        // hover in
        $("#box-1").css("background-color", "#DA4E51");

        $("#box-1 > .icon-link").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#box-1 > .text > p").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#icon-img-1").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png");
    },
    function () {
        // hover out
        $("#box-1").css("background-color", "#fafafa");
        $("#box-1").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-1 > .icon-link").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-1 > .text > p").css("color", "#000");
        $("#icon-img-1").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png");
    }
);

$("#box-2").hover(
    function () {
        // hover in
        $("#box-2").css("background-color", "#DA4E51");

        $("#box-2 > .icon-link").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#box-2 > .text > p").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#icon-img-2").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png");
    },
    function () {
        // hover out
        $("#box-2").css("background-color", "#fafafa");
        $("#box-2").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-2 > .icon-link").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-2 > .text > p").css("color", "#000");
        $("#icon-img-2").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png");
    }
);

$("#box-3").hover(
    function () {
        // hover in
        $("#box-3").css("background-color", "#DA4E51");

        $("#box-3 > .icon-link").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#box-3 > .text > p").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#icon-img-3").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png");
    },
    function () {
        // hover out
        $("#box-3").css("background-color", "#fafafa");
        $("#box-3").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-3 > .icon-link").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-3 > .text > p").css("color", "#000");
        $("#icon-img-3").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png");
    }
);

$("#box-4").hover(
    function () {
        // hover in
        $("#box-4").css("background-color", "#DA4E51");

        $("#box-4 > .icon-link").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#box-4 > .text > p").css("color", "#fff");
        $("#icon-img-4").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png");
    },
    function () {
        // hover out
        $("#box-4").css("background-color", "#fafafa");
        $("#box-4").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-4 > .icon-link").css("color", "#000");
        $("#box-4 > .text > p").css("color", "#000");
        $("#icon-img-4").attr("src", "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png");
    }
);
```

I want to make this simple. How can I do this? The loop is difficult for me.

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need javascript at all for this. You can change styling of elements on hover using css. You can have both images in the element but then hide/show the right image using css display block/none.

```
.box {
   background: white;
   color: black;
}

.box:hover {
   background: red;
   color: white;
}

.box:hover .img-1 {
   display: none
}

.box:hover .img-2 {
   display: block
}
```

```css
.wrapper-icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    width: 180px;
    margin: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #DA4E51;
}

.box:hover a.icon-link {
  color: #FFF;
}

.box:hover .icon-img-1 {
  display: none;
}

.box:hover .icon-img-2 {
  display: inline;
}

.box .text {
    padding: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}

a.icon-link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}

.icon-img-2 {
  display: none;
}

img { width: 70px; }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-icons">
  
  <div class="box">
    
    <a class="icon-link" href="https://google.com">
      
      <div class="text">
        
        <div class="title">
          
          <img class="icon-img-1" 
               src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/yellow-bird-icon.png" name="MyImage" />
          
          <img class="icon-img-2" 
               src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/fasticon/angry-birds/128/red-bird-icon.png" name="MyImage" />
          
        </div>
        
        <p class="box-text">SET1</p>
        
        <p>Movie</p>
        
      </div>
    </a>
    
  </div>

 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. dantheman93
Thanks for the answer.

I have to change the image and text (color, font, etc.) at the same time.

It doesn't work the way you told me.

I have already implemented
https://codepen.io/noxwon/pen/RwrmxKX
From this,

I used Jquery because it was difficult to operate with CSS alone.

Comment: You are very smart. It inspired me and it helped me a lot. Thank you :)